# Why are the common default shortcuts in terminal all use shift?

Tags: command-line, shortcuts

Like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for copy, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> for paste ... It's annoying since they're universal shortcuts, they shouldn't be different from everywhere else, but I'm guessing there was good reasons for this choice.
Could it cause issues to remove the Shift in those shortcuts ?

EDIT: After changing the shortcut in Ubuntu's terminal to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, programs termination is now automatically configured to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. This OS is pretty smart!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control keys are by default the [terminal settings](https://superuser.com/a/160389/478867). Every application you run can change these to their liking (e.g. ^C has no effect in `nano`)

You can list the settings using `stty -a`. You can for instance change the interrupt, which normally is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> using: `stty intr ^A`

If you are running the default Ubuntu terminal, you can also change the key-binding in menu `Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts...`.

There you will see that copy is mapped to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. If you change that to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, then you will have the behaviour you want.
Same for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

Comment: So there's no problem switching the keys then. That's what I was curious about. Also +1 because I didn't know you could change the signals keys, that's pretty cool. Thank you.

Comment: @Willy Yes, you can freely remap the keys. Of course, if you remap `ctrl-c` to 'copy', you will loose the 'interrupt function' unless you remap it to some other key-combination. All the editor programs do it all the time: they often let you remap the keys yourself (to match your favourite editor.)